# How can I get my subdomain to point to this WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a wordpess blog: mysite.wordpress.com

When I go to https://wordpress.com/domains/manage/mysite.wordpress.com and click Domains I see 2 domains:

1. **mysite.wordpress.com** (Primary)
2. **blog.mysite.com**

But when I try to make #2 my primary, it tells me it succeeded, but then reloading the page still shows #1 as the primary. And when I point my browser to **blog.mysite.com** it redirects to **mysite.wordpress.com**. Why?

I purchased the domain **mysite.com** from GoDaddy. And I have the domain records hosted in AWS. I believe what I need to do is tell AWS to point the nameservers for **blog.mysite.com** to Wordpress. But I can't find those nameservers. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. It may be related with browser cache. Can you try same things in other browser? Better if never used before with your site.